# not working one form two buttons to submit

Tags: design

i have phtml file which has two submit buttons of type submit or button. Either is not working. If i mention one button type as submit and other type as button, then its not posting the values in the redirected page.

```
<form id="form1" method="get">
    <label for="ID">ID: </label><input type="text" id="ID" name="ID"><br/>
    <label for="title">Title: </label><input type="text" id="title" name="title"><br/>
    <label for="filename">File Name: </label><input type="text" id="FileName" name="FileName"><br/>
    <label for="content">Content: </label><input type="text" id="Content" name="Content"><br/>
    <label for="status">Status: </label><input type="text" id="Status" name="Status"><br/>
    <div style="text-align: center"> <H1><input type="button" name="save" value="Save"
                                                onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::getUrl("test/index/save"); ?>')" />
    <input type="submit" name="Load" value="Load"
           onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::getUrl("test/index/load"); ?>')" ></H1></div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not the way to submit a form.
From what I see you want a way to submit a form to one page or an other, depending on the button that is clicked.

The form is not submitted if you, when you click it, you change the location of the page.

Try this instead.

```
<form id="form1" method="get" action="">
    <label for="ID">ID: </label><input type="text" id="ID" name="ID"><br/>
    <label for="title">Title: </label><input type="text" id="title" name="title"><br/>
    <label for="filename">File Name: </label><input type="text" id="FileName" name="FileName"><br/>
    <label for="content">Content: </label><input type="text" id="Content" name="Content"><br/>
    <label for="status">Status: </label><input type="text" id="Status" name="Status"><br/>
    <div style="text-align: center"> 
    <H1><input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" onclick="$('form1').action = '<?php echo Mage::getUrl("test/index/save"); ?>'" />
    <input type="submit" name="Load" value="Load"
           onclick="$('form1').action = '<?php echo Mage::getUrl("test/index/load"); ?>'" ></H1></div>
</form>
```

But in my opinion, a better idea would be to submit the form to one single URL and depending on the value of the button pressed ('save' or 'load') perform different actions.

Comment: if user enters new values then we show "inserted success" else "updated success" which are in two different pages & can we use method="get" which shows values in url

Answer (score 1):

```
onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::getUrl("test/index/load"); ?>')"
```

this doesn'r submit the form, it just changes the page. remove this and instead throw it into the `action` attribute of the `<form>`

Same here:

```
onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::getUrl("test/index/save"); ?>')"
```

What do you want to achieve? If you want to submit the form, you need a submit buttion without JS (or JS which submits the form and not changes the site)